# Longtable multirow problem

Tags: longtable, multirow

I have now tried to figure this out for the whole day, but I can't get it working.

My table headers for the longtable with multirow column names are overlapping the data itself. Can someone please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

(Most of the code is exported from my Python notebook, but I just can't figure out how to wrap the headers correctly in either Python or Latex.)

```
\begin{longtable}{SSSSSS}
\caption{Number and Percent of Family and Nonfamily Firms by Two-Digit SIC} \label{Table I:} \\

{\multirow{3}{1cm}{SIC}} & 
{\multirow{3}{2cm}{Nonfamily Firms}} & 
{\multirow{3}{2cm}{FamFirm}} & 
{\multirow{4}{2cm}{Percent Family Firms in Industry}} & 
{\multirow{4}{2cm}{Percent Founder CEO Firms in Industry}} & 
{\multirow{3}{2cm}{Percent Non-Founder Firms in Industry}} 
\\

\endfirsthead

\caption[]{Number and Percent of Family and Nonfamily Firms by Two-Digit SIC} \\
{\multirow{3}{1cm}{SIC}} & 
{\multirow{3}{2cm}{Nonfamily Firms}} & 
{\multirow{3}{2cm}{FamFirm}} & 
{\multirow{3}{2cm}{Percent Family Firms in Industry}} & 
{\multirow{3}{2cm}{Percent Founder CEO Firms in Industry}} & 
{\multirow{3}{2cm}{Percent Non-Founder Firms in Industry}} \\

\endhead
\multicolumn{6}{r}{Continued on next page} \\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot

10 & 16 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
13 & 44 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
15 & 7 & 4 & 36.400000 & 0.000000 & 36.400000 \\
16 & 15 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
20 & 54 & 58 & 51.800000 & 0.000000 & 51.800000 \\
21 & 9 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
22 & 0 & 10 & 100.000000 & 0.000000 & 100.000000 \\
23 & 8 & 8 & 50.000000 & 18.800000 & 50.000000 \\
24 & 9 & 10 & 52.600000 & 0.000000 & 52.600000 \\
25 & 8 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
26 & 49 & 24 & 32.900000 & 4.100000 & 32.900000 \\
27 & 27 & 55 & 67.100000 & 0.000000 & 67.100000 \\
28 & 149 & 57 & 27.700000 & 0.000000 & 27.700000 \\
29 & 57 & 11 & 16.200000 & 4.400000 & 11.800000 \\
30 & 25 & 26 & 51.000000 & 29.400000 & 21.600000 \\
31 & 9 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
32 & 7 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
33 & 57 & 25 & 30.500000 & 8.500000 & 22.000000 \\
34 & 35 & 18 & 34.000000 & 0.000000 & 34.000000 \\
35 & 92 & 55 & 37.400000 & 6.800000 & 30.600000 \\
36 & 77 & 29 & 27.400000 & 13.200000 & 14.200000 \\
37 & 87 & 41 & 32.000000 & 3.900000 & 28.100000 \\
38 & 67 & 19 & 22.100000 & 15.100000 & 7.000000 \\
39 & 14 & 8 & 36.400000 & 0.000000 & 36.400000 \\
40 & 32 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
42 & 2 & 5 & 71.400000 & 0.000000 & 71.400000 \\
45 & 34 & 7 & 17.100000 & 17.100000 & 0.000000 \\
48 & 23 & 16 & 41.000000 & 17.900000 & 23.100000 \\
49 & 8 & 4 & 33.300000 & 33.300000 & 0.000000 \\
50 & 20 & 8 & 28.600000 & 0.000000 & 28.600000 \\
51 & 41 & 2 & 4.700000 & 0.000000 & 4.700000 \\
52 & 14 & 7 & 33.300000 & 33.300000 & 0.000000 \\
53 & 38 & 19 & 33.300000 & 8.800000 & 24.600000 \\
54 & 9 & 25 & 73.500000 & 0.000000 & 73.500000 \\
55 & 0 & 7 & 100.000000 & 0.000000 & 100.000000 \\
56 & 15 & 28 & 65.100000 & 32.600000 & 32.600000 \\
57 & 15 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
58 & 7 & 5 & 41.700000 & 0.000000 & 41.700000 \\
59 & 14 & 20 & 58.800000 & 11.800000 & 52.900000 \\
60 & 0 & 8 & 100.000000 & 0.000000 & 100.000000 \\
61 & 21 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
62 & 8 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
63 & 87 & 20 & 18.700000 & 3.700000 & 15.000000 \\
64 & 9 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
70 & 0 & 14 & 100.000000 & 0.000000 & 100.000000 \\
72 & 0 & 17 & 100.000000 & 41.200000 & 58.800000 \\
73 & 43 & 24 & 35.800000 & 26.900000 & 9.000000 \\
75 & 8 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
78 & 10 & 6 & 37.500000 & 0.000000 & 37.500000 \\
79 & 12 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
80 & 12 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
87 & 7 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
99 & 19 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: You would need extra \\s after the header row to fill in the space that the `\multirow`s take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- I suggest you use the `xltabular` package and its eponymous environment instead of a `longtable` environment. That way, you can set up automatic linebreaking in the header cells. Basically, an `xltabular` environment combines the capabilities of the `longtable` and `tabularx` environments.
- I would round the number in the final 3 data columns to just 1 significant decimal digits. This is easily accompilished with the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type.
- Use the macros of the `booktabs` package to draw well-spaced horizontal lines.

The following screenshot shows the start of the first page of the resulting two-page table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,siunitx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
% handy shortcut macro:
\newcommand{\mC}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\hsize=#1\hsize}C}{#2}}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of next two instructions:
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textwidth}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} c T{3} T{2} 
      *{3}{T{3.1,round-mode=places,round-precision=1}} @{}}

\caption{Number and Percent of Family and Nonfamily Firms, by Two-Digit SIC} \label{Table_I} \\
\toprule
SIC & \mC{0.7}{Nonfamily Firms} & \mC{0.5}{Family Firms} & 
\mC{1.2}{Percent Family Firms in Industry} & 
\mC{1.3}{Percent Founder CEO Firms in Industry} & 
\mC{1.3}{Percent Non-Founder Firms in Industry} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, cont'd}\\[1ex]
\toprule
SIC & \mC{0.7}{Nonfamily Firms} & \mC{0.5}{Family Firms} & 
\mC{1.2}{Percent Family Firms in Industry} & 
\mC{1.3}{Percent Founder CEO Firms in Industry} & 
\mC{1.3}{Percent Non-Founder Firms in Industry} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{(Continued on next page)} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

10 & 16 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
13 & 44 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
15 & 7 & 4 & 36.400000 & 0.000000 & 36.400000 \\
16 & 15 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
20 & 54 & 58 & 51.800000 & 0.000000 & 51.800000 \\
21 & 9 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
22 & 0 & 10 & 100.000000 & 0.000000 & 100.000000 \\
23 & 8 & 8 & 50.000000 & 18.800000 & 50.000000 \\
24 & 9 & 10 & 52.600000 & 0.000000 & 52.600000 \\
25 & 8 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
26 & 49 & 24 & 32.900000 & 4.100000 & 32.900000 \\
27 & 27 & 55 & 67.100000 & 0.000000 & 67.100000 \\
28 & 149 & 57 & 27.700000 & 0.000000 & 27.700000 \\
29 & 57 & 11 & 16.200000 & 4.400000 & 11.800000 \\
30 & 25 & 26 & 51.000000 & 29.400000 & 21.600000 \\
31 & 9 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
32 & 7 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
33 & 57 & 25 & 30.500000 & 8.500000 & 22.000000 \\
34 & 35 & 18 & 34.000000 & 0.000000 & 34.000000 \\
35 & 92 & 55 & 37.400000 & 6.800000 & 30.600000 \\
36 & 77 & 29 & 27.400000 & 13.200000 & 14.200000 \\
37 & 87 & 41 & 32.000000 & 3.900000 & 28.100000 \\
38 & 67 & 19 & 22.100000 & 15.100000 & 7.000000 \\
39 & 14 & 8 & 36.400000 & 0.000000 & 36.400000 \\
40 & 32 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
42 & 2 & 5 & 71.400000 & 0.000000 & 71.400000 \\
45 & 34 & 7 & 17.100000 & 17.100000 & 0.000000 \\
48 & 23 & 16 & 41.000000 & 17.900000 & 23.100000 \\
49 & 8 & 4 & 33.300000 & 33.300000 & 0.000000 \\
50 & 20 & 8 & 28.600000 & 0.000000 & 28.600000 \\
51 & 41 & 2 & 4.700000 & 0.000000 & 4.700000 \\
52 & 14 & 7 & 33.300000 & 33.300000 & 0.000000 \\
53 & 38 & 19 & 33.300000 & 8.800000 & 24.600000 \\
54 & 9 & 25 & 73.500000 & 0.000000 & 73.500000 \\
55 & 0 & 7 & 100.000000 & 0.000000 & 100.000000 \\
56 & 15 & 28 & 65.100000 & 32.600000 & 32.600000 \\
57 & 15 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
58 & 7 & 5 & 41.700000 & 0.000000 & 41.700000 \\
59 & 14 & 20 & 58.800000 & 11.800000 & 52.900000 \\
60 & 0 & 8 & 100.000000 & 0.000000 & 100.000000 \\
61 & 21 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
62 & 8 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
63 & 87 & 20 & 18.700000 & 3.700000 & 15.000000 \\
64 & 9 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
70 & 0 & 14 & 100.000000 & 0.000000 & 100.000000 \\
72 & 0 & 17 & 100.000000 & 41.200000 & 58.800000 \\
73 & 43 & 24 & 35.800000 & 26.900000 & 9.000000 \\
75 & 8 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
78 & 10 & 6 & 37.500000 & 0.000000 & 37.500000 \\
79 & 12 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
80 & 12 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
87 & 7 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
99 & 19 & 0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `longtblr` defined in the `tabularray` package`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\NewTableCommand\mc{\SetCell{c}}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachfive}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {6}{5}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Number and Percent of Family and Nonfamily Firms, 
           by Two-Digit SIC},
  label = {Table_I}
                ]{ colsep = 4pt,
                  colspec = {@{} c
                            *{2}{X[1, c, si={table-format=3.0}]}
                            *{3}{X[2, c, si={table-format=3.2,
                                          round-mode=places,
                                          round-precision=2}]}
                            @{}},
                 row{2-Z} = {rowsep = 0pt},
                   row{1} = {font=\small, m},
            row{eachfive} = {abovesep=1ex},
                  rowhead = 1
                  }
    \toprule
SIC & \mc   {{{Nonfamily Firms}}}
    & \mc   {{{Family Firms}}}
    & \mc   {{{Percent Family\\ Firms in Industry}}}
    & \mc   {{{Percent Founder CEO Firms in Industry}}}
    & \mc   {{{Percent Non-Founder Firms in Industry}}} \\
    \midrule
10 &  16    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
13 &  44    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
15 &   7    &  4 &  36.400000 &  0.000000 &  36.400000 \\
16 &  15    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
20 &  54    & 58 &  51.800000 &  0.000000 &  51.800000 \\
21 &   9    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
22 &   0    & 10 & 100.000000 &  0.000000 & 100.000000 \\
23 &   8    &  8 &  50.000000 & 18.800000 &  50.000000 \\
24 &   9    & 10 &  52.600000 &  0.000000 &  52.600000 \\
25 &   8    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
26 &  49    & 24 &  32.900000 &  4.100000 &  32.900000 \\
27 &  27    & 55 &  67.100000 &  0.000000 &  67.100000 \\
28 & 149    & 57 &  27.700000 &  0.000000 &  27.700000 \\
29 &  57    & 11 &  16.200000 &  4.400000 &  11.800000 \\
30 &  25    & 26 &  51.000000 & 29.400000 &  21.600000 \\
31 &   9    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
32 &   7    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
33 &  57    & 25 &  30.500000 &  8.500000 &  22.000000 \\
34 &  35    & 18 &  34.000000 &  0.000000 &  34.000000 \\
35 &  92    & 55 &  37.400000 &  6.800000 &  30.600000 \\
36 &  77    & 29 &  27.400000 & 13.200000 &  14.200000 \\
37 &  87    & 41 &  32.000000 &  3.900000 &  28.100000 \\
38 &  67    & 19 &  22.100000 & 15.100000 &   7.000000 \\
39 &  14    &  8 &  36.400000 &  0.000000 &  36.400000 \\
40 &  32    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
42 &   2    &  5 &  71.400000 &  0.000000 &  71.400000 \\
45 &  34    &  7 &  17.100000 & 17.100000 &   0.000000 \\
48 &  23    & 16 &  41.000000 & 17.900000 &  23.100000 \\
49 &   8    &  4 &  33.300000 & 33.300000 &   0.000000 \\
50 &  20    &  8 &  28.600000 &  0.000000 &  28.600000 \\
51 &  41    &  2 &   4.700000 &  0.000000 &   4.700000 \\
52 &  14    &  7 &  33.300000 & 33.300000 &   0.000000 \\
53 &  38    & 19 &  33.300000 &  8.800000 &  24.600000 \\
54 &   9    & 25 &  73.500000 &  0.000000 &  73.500000 \\
55 &   0    &  7 & 100.000000 &  0.000000 & 100.000000 \\
56 &  15    & 28 &  65.100000 & 32.600000 &  32.600000 \\
57 &  15    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
58 &   7    &  5 &  41.700000 &  0.000000 &  41.700000 \\
59 &  14    & 20 &  58.800000 & 11.800000 &  52.900000 \\
60 &   0    &  8 & 100.000000 &  0.000000 & 100.000000 \\
61 &  21    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
62 &   8    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
63 &  87    & 20 &  18.700000 &  3.700000 &  15.000000 \\
64 &   9    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
70 &   0    & 14 & 100.000000 &  0.000000 & 100.000000 \\
72 &   0    & 17 & 100.000000 & 41.200000 &  58.800000 \\
73 &  43    & 24 &  35.800000 & 26.900000 &   9.000000 \\
75 &   8    &  0 &   0.000000 &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
78 &  10    &  6 &  37.500000 &  0.000000 &  37.500000 \\
79 &  12    &  0 &  0.000000  &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
80 &  12    &  0 &  0.000000  &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
87 &   7    &  0 &  0.000000  &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
99 &  19    &  0 &  0.000000  &  0.000000 &   0.000000 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Just curious why you're setting a precision of 2 decimal digits?

Comment: For some reason, I get an extra "Z" above the table label, which I can't figure out. Also, Overleaf throws a "Missing number, treated as zero" error.

Comment: @AlexGünsberg, unfortunately Overleaf still has installed quite old version of `tabularray` package which not support options `Z` in columns/rows numbering. Hopefully they will upgrade their LaTeX installation soon. Ask their support if and how you can load recent package (2022B) locally to your Overleaf folder.

Comment: @Zarko many thanks for the advice and the beautiful piece of code!

Comment: @AlexGünsberg, your are welcome! Now you have sufficient reputation that you can upvote bot answers :-)